# Distributing vagrant VM locally

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

I have set up a vagrant vm on my machine. (Virtualbox)

I would like to be able to share this VM amongst other machines however would like to avoid having to download the image repeatedly.

I tried Exporting the Appliance and copying the Vagrantfile folder onto a different machine, however when i tried to connect using vagrant ssh it could not find it. I assume this is because of non-matching UUID's. How can I go around this?

Vagrant version 1.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use Vagrant Package

```
vagrant package --base <Name Of VM on virtualbox>
```

This creates a package.box file in your current directory.

You then share that package.box file, and on the new computers you execute:

```
vagrant init package.box
```

in the directory where the Vagrantfile will be created